# Is this sentence correctly spelled in Japanese Kanji using plural suffix

Tags: kanji, plural-suffixes

I am trying to write:

I have three game versions of Bio Hazard.

> わたし 三つ  バイオハザード ゲーム版達が あります

```
Watashi mittsu baiohazādo gēmu-ban-tachi ga arimasu
```

Is this correctly written?

Comment: Is there a reason you feel you need to insert 達?  It sounds a bit odd here.  Also, the number does not usually precede that which you are counting.  It would more naturally follow the が.

Comment: We don’t do translations here, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[We don't provide bulk proofreading service](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/5010), so allow me to give an answer only with respect to the "plural suffix". Here, you shouldn't use 達 or any other such suffix. Many languages, including Japanese, do not have a rule that nouns must always have a suffix like the English "s" if they are plural. 達 is not for that purpose.

- [What is the difference in usage between a plural using (a) the kanji repetition character 々, (b) a plural using -たち, and (c) the singular?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8105/5010)

  > In English (and in many other languages), every noun must be marked as singular or plural. In Japanese marking plurality for a noun is not mandatory. This does not mean that Japanese speakers can't convey the idea that a noun is singular or plural if they want to, it only means they don't have to — and indeed in most cases Japanese speakers will not explicitly specify if whether a noun is singular or plural.

People do sometimes attach 達 after a noun for a certain reason, but this is not relevant in your case: [Can 達 be used to pluralize inanimate things?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33511/5010)

Your sentence has some other mistakes, which I won't go into in detail, but the correct version of what you might be trying to say would be バイオハザードのゲームを3バージョン持っています or something.